# How to manage multiple ajax request/responses with a for loop and an array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an ajax request using a For loop and an array in JQuery mobile.

I am trying to:

1. Send all the requests.
2. Store all the responses.
3. After all Ajax completed, perform another action.

Here's what I have so far that doesn't really work (that's why I'm here).

```
var req1 = [];
var req2 = [];
var size = //some number passed to here//;

//Create size number of unique ajax json requests
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        requestA[i] = // GET request for json datatype //;
        requestB[i] = $.ajax(requestA[i]);   
};

for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    requestB[j].done (function (response) {   
        if (response[j].results.length > 0) (      
            requestB[j] = response[j].results;            
        }
});   

$(document).ajaxStop (function() {
        // Do this after all ajax is done //   
});
```

Comment: You are missing a `}` after you last `for` loop,

Answer (score 0):

Try to lock array when you in a callback.

Something like this

```
var isLoked = false;

// ...
if (response[j].results.length > 0 && !isLocked) (
        isLocked = true;    
        requestB[j] = response[j].results;            
        isLocked = false;
}
```

P.S. Why you dont want make request and assign callback at the same loop?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you are doing it this way i would use `$.when` to rig up the callback... and can pass all the responses in to that.

```
var req = [];
var size = 5;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // not sure what the signicance of A and B arrays are here...
        requestA[i] = // GET request for json datatype //;
        requestB[i] = $.ajax(requestA[i]);

       // but we want to push them all onto req
       req.push(requestA[i]);
       req.push(requestB[i]);  
};

// so we need a callback for when they are all finished:
jQuery.when.apply(null, req).then(successFunction, failFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I like how clean this is.  I'm trying it now.  But how does it know only to perform the req.push after it gets a response?  That's why I was wrapping it in a .done.

Comment: Oh yeah...here's another part of the same problem...each request returns multiple items.  Arrrggghhh!  My brain hurts.